# Why ReactiveForm from Angular erase my option value from a Select?

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a strange problem in my component.html i have this code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- < form item -->
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uf'>UF</label>
            <select formControlName="compUf" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.compUf.errors }" class='custom-select' id='uf'>

              <option selected>-- Selecione --</option>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let field of this.states | keyvalue">
                <option [value]="field.key" [selected]="field.key === 'AC'">{{ field.key }}</option>
              </ng-container>

            </select>
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.compUf.errors" class="invalid-feedback error-msg-form">
              <div *ngIf="f.compUf.errors.required">Este campo é obrigatório</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- form item /> -->
        </div>
```

This code populates a select with no problem, but this line is not working [selected]="field.key === 'AC'", i think the problem it was with my code, but when i remove this atribute from ReactiveForm formControlName="compUf" it works i don't know why!

This is my code on component.ts that i create the form:

```
this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      compCnpj: ['', [Validators.required,GenericValidator.isValidCnpj()]],
      compFantasy: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(200)]],
      compSocial: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(200)]],
      compRevenue: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compRhName: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(150)]],
      compRhCell: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compRhPhone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compRhEmail: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      compResCompName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compResName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(150)]],
      compCorresp: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
      compResPhone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compAgreementDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compOfiNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compAgrePayDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compCutDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compPayDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compCep: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compUf: [Validators.required],
      compCity: [Validators.required],
      compNeigh: ['', [Validators.required]],
      compAddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)]],
      compNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]],
      compComplement: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)]]
    });
```

I was thinking, that the problem was the default value from formBuilder so i remove the '' from compUf, but the problem persist.

what's wrong?

Comment: You should set the default value on the form control and not use `selected` in your template.

Comment: I can't do this dynamically? In this example if you put [selected]="order.id == 2" on second formControl, it is working dynamically

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditionaldropdown-gnajge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html